# How to create a list of images and their size (resolution)?

Tags: image, list, file

Is it possible to create a list of image files in a directory with their file names and the width and height in pixels, and save it as a CSV, for instance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there's an app for that - Directory List & Print Pro.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ImageMagick**:

```
identify -format '%w,%h,%f\n' *.jpg *.png *.tif > images.csv
```

**Sample Output**

```
474,478,a.jpg
500,505,b.jpg
2756,1034,image.jpg
1830,1830,result.jpg
600,600,test.jpg
```

If you are running any disreputable OSes from Redmond that need to be told twice it's the end of the line, change `\n` to `\r\n`.

Comment: Note that I have since written a more complete answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69229350/2836621