# command to print images with pixel size within directory

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

is it possible to list all images in a directory that have pixel size grater or smaller than x?
I found this command on another thread

```
find . -name '*.png' -exec file {} \; | sed 's/\(.*png\): .* \([0-9]* x [0-9]*\).*/\2 \1/' | awk 'int($1) < 250 {print}'
```

this command works well for *.png, but the moment I change it to *.jpg the results get too crazy. see below. I would like to write the results to a log file so that I can later delete these images from my product catalog.

*.png output

```
50 x 50 ./data/catalog/agsquare.png
220 x 138 ./data/catalog/brickwall_@2X.png
3 x 3 ./data/catalog/dots.png
98 x 98 ./data/catalog/grid-noise.png
```

*jpg output (the pixel size is ignored, something is clearly wrong with this command)

```
./data/background/fashion-shirt.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1920x1440, frames 3
./data/background/grey-bag.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1920x1280, frames 3
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 3):

`file` outputs `1 x 2` for PNG but `1x2` for JPEG. Your command expects the spaces.

Instead, use a tool like `identify` from ImageMagick that can do this in a format independent manner:

```
find . \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) \
    -exec identify -format '%w %h %i\n' {} + |
    awk '$1 < 250'
```

Comment: I think you need `%f` rather than `%F`.

Comment: `%f` is only the filename, `%F` includes the path

Comment: No longer, I think... https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

Comment: Interesting. `%f` fails on my 6.9.11-24. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm on v7.1.0-5

Comment: thanks, while the "identify" command did not work, probably because imagemaic is not installed, removing the space worked. I run this and got the same output like the *.png output.                                                                                                                                 find . -name '*.jpg' -exec file {} \; | sed 's/\(.*jpg\): .* \([0-9]*x[0-9]*\).*/\2 \1/' | awk 'int($1) < 260 {print}'

Comment: @MarkSetchell Apparently `%i` works on both. `%f` on 7.1.0.7-1 still just prints the basename and not the path

Comment: hi, have another question, this command evaluates the width < 260, what do i need to change so that it will evaluate the height, the second field of the dimension. I can use run a separate command if it is easier. - thanks

Comment: `$2 < 260` would compare the height

Answer (score 2):

In order of simplest to more heavy-weight, you have several options:

- `feh`
- `exiftool`
- `ffprobe` - little friend of `ffmpeg`
- **ImageMagick** `identify`

---

According the [Ubuntu package repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/), you should have `feh` installed in Ubuntu 18 LTS, so you can use:

```
feh -L "%f:%w:%h"  *.jpg *.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
small.png:10:10
red.jpg:8:8
redhat.jpg:254:255
```

Note `feh` also accepts `—min-dimension` and `—max-dimension` as filters. So, for all images wider than 640 px, use:

```
feh --min-dimension 640x0 -L "%f:%w:%h"  *.jpg *.png
```

---

You can also use `exiftool` to find and print images with height or width less than 100 px like this:

```
exiftool -p '$filename:$imagewidth:$imageheight' -if '$imagesize and ($imagewidth<100 or $imageheight<100)' -q *.jpg *.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
black.jpg:8:8
red.jpg:8:8
small.png:10:10
```

If you are on any *"operating system"* originating from Redmond, replace the single quotes with double quotes.

Note that `exiftool` is a **significantly smaller** installation than **ImageMagick**.

---

[Ubuntu 18 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/) should also include `ffmpeg` and its little friend `ffprobe`, so you can do:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width,height  -of csv=p=0:s=x IMAGEFILE
```

---

Or with **ImageMagick**, use this to find images with width<100:

```
magick identify -format '%f:%w:%h\n' *png *jpg | awk -F: '$2<100'
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the other guy I removed the spaces around the x and it worked. failed to mention that I did not want to use any tool, the other commands could not be found on my server.

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec file {} \; | sed 's/\(.*jpg\): .* \([0-9]*x[0-9]*\).*/\2 \1/' | awk 'int($1) < 250 {print}'
```